# JSON onFailure issue

Tags: php, html, ajax, json

I’m having trouble getting a AJAX/JSON function to work correctly. I had this function grabbing value from a drop down box but now I want to use an anchor tag to set it's value.

I thought it would be easy to just use the onClick event to pass string to the function I was using for the drop down box but I get the alert in JSON onFailure event even though data gets added to MySQL. I tried removing the alert from `onFailure` event but then it doesn't add the data. The drop down still continues work work fine, no alerts. (I should note that removing the alert also broke my drop down box)

1st I add an onClick event…

```
<a href="<?php echo Settings::get('app.webroot'); ?>?view=schedule&action=questions" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('bre','','template/images/schedule/bre_f2.gif',1)" onclick="assignCallType('testing')";>
```

2nd I check main.js.php

```
function assignCallType(type) {
  alert(type);
  new Request.JSON({
    url: "ajax.php",
    onSuccess: function(rtndata, txt) {
      if (rtndata['STATUS'] != 'OK')
        alert('Status was not okay');
    },
    onFailure: function() {
      alert("onFailure")
    }
  }).get({
    'action': 'assignCallType',
    'call_type': type
  });
}
```

3rd Ajax.php: the variable is back in PHP and values get added to MySQL but I get the Alert in the JSON onFailure event

```
if ($_GET['action'] == "assignCallType") {
    if ($USER->isInsideSales()) {
        $call_type = $_GET['call_type'];
        $_SESSION['callinfo']->setCallType($call_type);
        $_SESSION['callinfo']->save($callid);
        echo json_encode(array('STATUS'=>'OK'));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('STATUS'=>'DENIED'));
    }
}
```

Any idea where I am going wrong. The only difference between this and the working drop down is how the function was called, I used `onchange="assignCallType(this.value)"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the callback for `onFailure` provide any arguments? For example in jQuery there are 3 arguments that can give you information about the error. I ran into a similar problem where the `error` callback kept getting called even though there was no connection error. The problem turned out to be badly-formed JSON. Can you confirm that your JSON is well-formed?

**UPDATE**

I just checked out the documentation for [`Request`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request) and noticed that `onFailure` can have `xhr` in its signature. Try taking a look at the `status`, `statusText`, and `responseText` attributes of the `XMLHttpRequest` object. That will give you a clue as to what's going wrong.

Try this:

```
onFailure: function(xhr) {
   console.log(xhr.status, xhr.statusText, xhr.responseText);
}
```

Comment: I think your right--however I don't get the error with the drop down box... also if I leave out onFailure all together I doesn't add the data to mySQL, sorry I don't understand Mootools enough to check the XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: even if I have onFailure do anything but an alert it doesn't add data...man I'mm confused.

Comment: Try changing the onFailure handler to what I've shown above in my answer.